# Extending Counter to huge lists? (Python)

Tags: python, counter, intersection, large-data

I am trying to find the length of the intersection of two arrays counted with multiplicities (i.e. if the same element is found 3 times in one array and 5 times in the other, I want it to be counted exactly three times). Here's the code I use:

```
intrs = Counter(t1) & Counter(t2)
count = sum(intrs.values())
```

Unfortunately this code returns a MemoryError when the lists are too large, for example, 8M objects each. Is there any way to make the algorithm work for large lists?

Comment: I think in this case you should use numpy.
Great library when using large scale lists.
It has a built in, array like object, that you can manipulate with great preformance.

Comment: numpy will not solve memory errors(in general at least) ... because numpy arrays require contiguous memory, they actually are harder to allocate memory for than normal python lists and dictionaries

Comment: Does the memory error occur only when you build the Counters or actually when the lists are built?

Comment: a database is what you want to use for this type of problem ...

Comment: Can you be more specific as to which part of your code fails. The list creation, the counter initialisation, the intersection, ...?

Comment: you could try creating the counter from list one ... then deleteing list1, then create the counter for list2, and delete list2, then intersect them ... maybe it might work ... its really hard to say with any certainty ... it probably isnt the sum at a guess... but who knows

Comment: Creating these counters shouldn't be a major memory issue for 8-million-object input lists. You must be using a lot more memory somewhere else.

Comment: @user2357112 if hes using 32bit he is limited to 2gb ... and a 2 x 8million lists creating counters (especially if there are not many duplicates in the list creates a dictionary with up to 8 million key value pairs in it (16 million values per counter)) == 32 million entries just for the counters (not counting the overhead of the original lists and the new intersected list) ... so yeah i can see it eating up all his memory (Especially if the items in the lists are more than just ints or something easy)

Comment: @JoranBeasley: A quick test of `sys.getsizeof(dict.fromkeys(range(8*10**6)))` says yeah, I was underestimating the per-entry overhead of a dict. I didn't account for the load factor and the cached hashes. The 3 counters created here could be over a gigabyte put together on a 64-bit system, not counting element sizes (since those costs were already incurred).

Comment: @user2357112 thanks for double checking :) always good to make sure im not off my rocker yet (also as an aside im not sure `sys.getsizeof` is entirely trustworthy :P)

Comment: @Max You can try to use `sqlite` db, load data there end use SQL command to find intersection.